# boost asio - check whether there is anything to read from a serial port

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port, boost-asio

I'm using the boost::asio library to control a motor with serial connection. The problem is that the boost::asio::serial_port::read() function would get the program to freeze if the device does not send anything for me to read.

How can I check whether the device has something to tell me through the port?

If I send a command to the device, I can get an answer back with no problems. But is there a way to know whether it sent anything without me sending a command? or does that not make any sense in serial connections, where a command is only received as a response to a sent command?

Please check my code

```
try
{
    port = new boost::asio::serial_port(io_serial, comPort.c_str());
}
char rcvd;
std::string res;
while(1)
{
    boost::asio::read(*port,boost::asio::buffer(&rcvd, 1)); //here it freezes till something is read
    std::cout<<rcvd<<std::endl; //I know it froze in the last line because nothing was written from here
    if(rcvd == '\r' || rcvd == '\0')
    {
        break;
    }
    res.push_back(rcvd);
}
return res;
```

Thanks for any efforts.

Comment: Why not use async read with boost::asio::async_read_*?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I don't know actually what the difference would make. Could you please explain the difference?

Comment: It cannot says you, that there are data in port... But it will not block execution (until you call ios.run()) and you can set timeout (and if timeout happens - there is no data in port)... I think in asio, there is no function, that can says you, that port has any data for send.

Comment: Actually, I didn't find any timeout method. Could you please point out how a timeout can be used with it?

Comment: You should use http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer.html example of usage http://liveworkspace.org/code/m4kRJ$11

Comment: In case the the software is windows only, you can use the Win32 function SetCommTimeouts on the native handle to set a timeout on the blocking read. However, I agree that using the async_read is the way to go.

Comment: @jcm I tried to use     COMMTIMEOUTS Timeout;  GetCommTimeouts((port->native_handle()),&Timeout); but the program still stalls. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you set ReadIntervalTimeout=MAXDWORD, ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier=0, ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=0? Using the raw Win32 API you can make the serial port read non-blocking. I have to confess that I never tried that through asio (I use async_read in that case). That timeout trick might not work.

Comment: @jcm Thanks for the effort, but it didn't work... if you have any other ideas, please let me know. Using async_read isn't really simple and the documentation of boost is pretty shitty. I don't want to have my PhD on boost::asio... I wish there is really a simple example to the idea.

Comment: There are no examples about serial port in the documentation, but the documentation isn't bad for TCP. Check the tutorial and examples for a TCP client to learn about the async_read and the callbacks. In your case you use async_read_until and your callback function or method will be called when the motor sent you a complete command. You don't necessarily need a timeout (but it can be useful if you need some action if the motor didn't sent something for a certain time).

Comment: In case you really prefer to poll for new characters on the serial port and you don't need portability, then don't use asio but the Win32 API. Open the serial port with `CreateFile`, do a `SetCommState`, do a `SetCommTimeouts` with the parameters as in the previous comment. Read the data with `ReadFile`. It won't block if the timeouts have been initialised correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For serial ports, Boost.Asio neither provides non-blocking synchronous reads nor reads with timeouts.  Therefore, the alternative option is to use asynchronous reads.  Boost.Asio provides [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/async_tcp_client.cpp) example.  While the example is for TCP, it should exemplify the overall concepts and approach to asynchronous reads with timeouts.

Additionally, based on the posted logic, where data is read until a carriage-return or NULL, it may be worth considering using a [line-based operation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/line_based.html), such as [`boost::asio::async_read_until`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until.html).